# What is (∃!e) in Davidson 1967?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, quantification, formalisation

Davidson proposes a causal law for singular event causation. Here is one example of a backward-looking part of such a law (changed slightly for clarity and to avoid copyright infringement):

(e)(u)((Ge & (t(e) = u + ε)) -> (∃!q)(Fq & (t(q) = n) & C(q,e)))

Notes:

- e, q are event variables
- G, F are event predicate variables
- u is a time
- let me know if anything else is unclear

**Problem**:

What is "(∃!q)"? I wasn't able to find this notation on google, nor in an article on Davidson's theory of causation (e.g. Wirderker 1985).

My gut instinct is that this has to be simply (∃q). Then much of the formalism makes sense.

Yet obviously "!" is often used for negation. But in a law-denoting conditional, why would a universally quantified statement over events lead to the negation of a statement that an event exists that caused it?

Edit: answered.

Comment: ∃! means "exists and is unique", it is a standard notation, see [Uniqueness quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification).

Comment: Answered, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Exchange user [Conifold](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/9148/conifold) left their answer as a comment.

I will re-post [Conifold](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/9148/conifold)'s comment as an official answer to question:

> `∃!` means "exists and is unique"

There is a Wikipedia page on [Uniqueness Quantification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification) for reference here:

Comment: It is really awesome that my answer keeps getting downv-oted even though the answer is correct. For most questions on this website, what the the correct answer is very uncertain. However, this time, it is not up for debate. in Davidson (1967) used `∃! x` to say "there exists unique x"